# Can dojo 1.7.1 using AMD provide code assist in Aptana 3?

Tags: dojo, aptana, content-assist, code-assist, js-amd

I've tried to get Aptana studio 3 to provide dojo 1.7.1 code-assist without success.

AMD - Asynchronous Module Definition.

Using asynchronous module loading (via [AMD](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD) support in dojo 1.7) on a simple web page:

```
require([ "dojo/dom", "dojo/fx", "dojo/_base/fx", "dojo/_base/array", "dojo/domReady!"], 
    function(dom, fx, fxbase, array) { ... });
```

How do I get code-assist on variables dom, fx, fxbase, ...?

Comment: I don't know what you are using "AMD" for, but I can tell you that you are the only one using it so in the first twenty results for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amd . Perhaps you should expand it, just in case the acronym is widely used to designate something programming-related other than what you mean.

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: He is referring to [AMD modules](http://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), one of the big new features in Dojo 1.7. I don't know what is the correct SO tag for it though.

Comment: @missingno Let's try "dojo-amd" and see if it catches on.

Comment: I'm newbie with javascript documentation, but I wonder if the AMD api is _fundamentally incompatible_ with javascript 'code assist' techniques. Unless the IDE understands `require()` syntax, how can it know the types of variables 'dom', 'fx', and so forth, and hence provide code-assist?

Comment: @Complicatedseebio: turns out there already is a "js-amd" tag that fits the bill

Answer (score 2):

Aptana may not be able to deal with AMD on its own, as the syntax is relatively new.  However, Aptana used to be able to consume a metadata file from Dojo's release.  That wouldn't help you with code completion for your own AMD code, but it might help with Dojo methods.  It might have been [this one](http://download.dojotoolkit.org/release-1.7.1/api.xml), but I'm not sure what the process was for Aptana to consume the file.

Comment: thanks for the link, but I've tried that file and it doesn't seem to help with code like my example. That's why I tried to be specific with the "dom, fx, array" variables which are injected instances of dojo's dojo/dom, dojo/fx, and dojo/_base/array respectively. I'm after code completion for those established interfaces.